# ajax on submit no refresh form using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

ok so i know this ajax works, but i cant seem to understand why it's not submitting here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "postitem.php",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

submit form

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" id="myform">
```

submit button

```
<input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" /> 
<button type="submit" title="Done" style="height:33px; width:50px">
    <img src="../../css/images/plus_25.png" />
</button>
```

i'm pretty something is wrong with the button, but i want to keep the way the button is because alot of my other forms use this same button, thanks if you can explain to me why click this submit button does nothing.

Comment: You don't have a `input[type=submit]` in your form. you have a `button[type=submit]` and an `input[type=hidden]`

Comment: so just change input[type=sumbit] to button[type=submit] ?

Comment: `<button type="submit">` is meaningless.  `type` only exists on `<input>`.

Comment: The `type` attribute is valid for `<button>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are selecting an `<input>` instead of a `<button>`. I had success by changing your jQuery selector from this:

```
$('input[type=submit]')
```

to this:

```
$('button[type=submit]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H3Bcc/

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers interpret a `click` attached to a submit button as submitting the form so you are effectively just negating the click of that button.

Preventing a form submission should preferably be captured by attaching the `submit` handler to the `<form>` when you have a `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit>` so this is the best way to assure success:

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e){

        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="postitem.php" method="POST" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" /> 
    <button type="submit" title="Done" style="height:33px; width:50px">
        <img src="../../css/images/plus_25.png" />
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You forgot parentheses. `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Agreed, this is better practice. But it doesn't answer the OPs specific question of why the original code fails.

Comment: can you show me how to code should look like with the e.preventdefault();

Comment: Sure can, it's in the code I gave above, do you have specific questions regarding it?

Comment: My bad I used a period instead of a comma, the new update reflects this: `$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){`

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser's default action of submitting 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "postitem.php",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: wait, why do this exactly? i'm new to ajax

Comment: this will prevent the browser default action from submitting and it will use ajax to submit instead